# Did Hegel have a response to solipsism?

Tags: hegel, solipsism

Did Hegel have a response to solipsism?

I have read little Hegel, but I like the idea that he did have a response to solipsism.

Comment: [This](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/019145379802400505?journalCode=pscb) looks relevant but over my head

Comment: Some take the master-slave dialectic from Phenomenology of Spirit as a refutation of solipsism, see e.g. [Hesiod's corner](https://hesiodscorner.wordpress.com/2018/07/30/hegel-dialectical-self-consciousness-lordship-bondsman-sec-178-196-phenomenology-of-spirit/):"*Self-consciousness exists in and for itself when, and by the fact that, it also exists for another, that is to say, it **is** only by being acknowledged or “recognized”*".

Comment: an interesting read thanks @Conifold though starting with "Apart from the preface, and other famous sections within the Phenomenology of Spirit, the most famous section of Hegel’s Phenomenology is" makes it seem a little untrustworthy... no-one wants to answer the question with references?